# Borrar carpeta y los archivos que la contienen con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una carpeta en el servidor con una ruta similar a: "/var/tmp/files/", dentro de ella tengo sub-carpetas llamadas con el ID de usuario que sube los archivos (Ej. 99, 101, 102, 167...). Dentro de estas carpetas puede haber 1 o varios archivos en distintos formatos de imágenes y pdfs.

- /var/tmp/files

  - 99

    - 99_img.jpg
    - 99_pdf.pdf
  - 101

    - 101_img.png
  - 102

  ... etc

Quiero indicar un ID y que se borren todas las subcarpetas + archivos que hay dentro, siempre que sean menores a ese ID indicado (más antiguos). Es decir, si indico el número 102, se deberán borrar el 102, 101, 99... Pero no el 167.

Por otra parte, tengo problema con los permisos, al intentar borrar algo, aunque sea directamente con unlink, me avisa:

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(/var/tmp/files/131/imagen.png): Permission denied
```

Lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
$dir_adjuntos = "/var/tmp/files/"
$path = $dir_adjuntos ."131";
$this->rrmdir($path);

public function rrmdir($dir) { 

    if (is_dir($dir)) { 
        $objects = scandir($dir); 
        foreach ($objects as $object) { 
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
            if (is_dir($dir."/".$object)) {
                $this->rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
            }
            else {
                unlink($dir."/".$object); 
            }
        }
    }
    $this->rrmdir($dir); 
    } 
}
```

Cómo puedo solucionar que se borren las carpetas con ID <= al que especifico?
Cómo soluciono el error de los permisos? Acepto cualquier propuesta de mejora y optimización de código, por supuesto, cualquier consejo es bienvenido para seguir aprendiendo. Gracias!

Comment: Espero que esta pequeña aportación te ayude a solucionar tu problema.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it]

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto podría funcionarte.

```
$maxID = '120';
$dir_adjuntos = "/var/tmp/files/"
$path = $dir_adjuntos ."131";
$this->rrmdir($path);

public function rrmdir($dir) { 

    if (is_dir($dir) and ($dir < $maxID) {
        chmod($dir, '0777'); 
        $objects = scandir($dir); 
        foreach ($objects as $object) { 
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
            if (is_dir($dir."/".$object)) {
                $this->rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
            }
            else {
                chmod($object, '0777');
                unlink($dir."/".$object); 
            }
        }
    }
    $this->rrmdir($dir); 
    } 
}
```

Con una variable que nos indique cual es el ID máximo, la comparamos al inicio de todo, cuando evaluamos si estamos en una carpeta o no. En caso de ser una carpeta, además le cambiamos los permisos para luego poderla borrar

Más adelante, justo antes de hacer el unlink, hacemos un chmod para que nos cambie los permisos en la carpeta y que permita su borrado